# Python - PyQt5 Using Threads Properly

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I'm new to Threads. I get AssertionError when I use the code below and I could not be able to fix it. Actually, I'm trying this just to learn, I will use the technique with bigger data. Please ignore the length of the database. My question is How can I fix this error, where is the error?
**The error I get =>

assert tlock.locked()
AssertionError:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys
import time

class Thread(QThread):
    out_signal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        import apriori
        l2 = [['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']]
        results = apriori.ap(l2, 0.4)
        for i in results:
            self.out_signal.emit(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)

class main_window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(main_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)
        self.components()
    def components(self):
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("EXECUTE")
        self.list1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.list1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.run_algo)

        self.show()
    def run_algo(self):
        self.list1.clear()
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.out_signal.connect(self.accept)
        self.thread.start()
        self.count = 1

    def accept(self, item):
        self.list1.insertItem(self.count, str(item))
        self.count+=1


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
uyg = main_window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is `apriori`? The code should work fine without that.

Comment: Apriori is one of the data mining algorithms. It's not an embedded function of python, I implemented the algorithm myself. The code works fine. I get the correct results on the list. But when I close the GUI, I get the error. I think the error is about not closing the thread, but I am not sure.

Comment: Try adding `def closeEvent(self, event): self.thread.quit(); self.thread.wait(1000); super().closeEvent(event)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This additional code looks like solved my problem.